# How was this boolean expression further simplified?

Tags: language-agnostic, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

```
(ab+cd)(a'b'+c'd') = 1+ abc'd' + a'b'cd +1
```

so I'm stuck at

```
abc'd'+a'b'cd
```

but the final answer is

```
(a+b)(c+d)+(a'+b')(c'+d')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean to have `0`s there instead?

Comment: where? in my answer or the correct final answer or in the question?

Comment: At your first simplification.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry bout that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that those two expressions are complementary, i.e. the only two cases where `(a+b)(c+d)+(a'+b')(c'+d')` are false are `abc'd'` and `a'b'cd`.

**Edit:** Somewhere along the line I think you've lost a `'` and you're actually looking for one of these:

```
((ab+cd)(a'b'+c'd'))'
(ab+cd)'+(a'b'+c'd')'
((ab)'(cd)')+((a'b')'(c'd')')
(a'+b')(c'+d')+(a+b)(c+d)
(a+b)(c+d)+(a'+b')(c'+d')

(ab+cd)(a'b'+c'd')
(a'b'+c'd')(ab+cd)
((a+b)'+(c+d)')((a'+b')'+(c'+d')')
((a+b)(c+d))'((a'+b')(c'+d'))'
((a+b)(c+d)+(a'+b')(c'+d'))'
```

Comment: huh wait.. i know what the law of complementary is but i dont understand, is my current answer in the wrong track?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you you were actually supposed to take the complement of the original expression?

Comment: I was supposed to simplify this (ab+cd)(a'b'+c'd')

Answer (score 0):

you cannot prove that `(ab+cd)(a'b'+c'd') = (a+b)(c+d)+(a'+b')(c'+d')` because it is not true.

take `a=b=1, c=d=0`:

`(ab+cd)(a'b'+c'd') = (1+0)(0+1) = 1`

but

`(a+b)(c+d)+(a'+b')(c'+d') = (1*0)+(0*1) = 0`

(assuming `x'` is "not")